# Sentences about sets : closed, boundary, limit points

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I want to check which of the following sentences are correct.

1. In $\mathbb{R} $ with the usual metric the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left [0,1-\frac{1}{2n}\right] $ is closed.
2. In $\mathbb{R} $ with the usual metric the boundary of a set can be larger than the set.
3. If in a metric space a set has no limit points then the set is closed.
4. In $\mathbb{R} $ with the usual metric the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left [n,n+\frac{1}{2n}\right] $ is closed.

$$$$

I think (2) is correct, since $\partial \mathbb{Q} =\mathbb{R} $ and the set of reals is larger than the set of rationals.

(3) is also correct and we prove that using the closure : each point of $cl(S) - S$ is a limit point of $S$. In general it holds that $S$ is a subset of $cl(S) $. Since there are no limit points we have that $cl(S) - S=\emptyset$ and so $cl(S) =S$ and so the set is closed.

The union of sentence (1) is equal to $[0,1]$, or not? If yes, this set is closed, isn't it?

The union of sentence (4) is equal to $[1,\infty) $, or not? If yes, this set is not closed, right ?

Comment: By larger, do you mean has greater cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in (1) is equal to $[0,1)$, not closed. If by larger you mean has greater cardinality, your reasoning for (2) is correct.
Your reasoning for claim (3) is correct. The expression in (4) is not equal to $[1, \infty)$, as @GingFreecs17 pointed out. The expression in (4) is closed, because its complement is equal to
$$
(-\infty,1) \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+\frac{1}{2n},n+1),
$$
which is a union of open sets.

Comment: be careful with (4). It has multiples pieces.

Comment: [1,1+1/2] U [2,2+1/4] U...   there is no element from (3/4,2)

Comment: @GingFreecss17 You are right, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)